# Is sahi open source supports build tools like ANT/MAVEN/GRADLE?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-2, gradle, sahi

Is sahi open source supports build tools like Ant/ Maven/ Gradel?If yes,please share the info that could help me to run sahi test cases?

Comment: The question could be answered by reading the documentation cause it's commericial tool. So the tool creator should provided such information.

Comment: You can invoke Sahi Tests via Ant and Java. So anything which can run Java is able to start tests.

Answer (score 1):

Sahi Test can be started by Ant and Java and therefor by Maven and Gradle too.

An easy way to get that information is to use google or to search the sahi site http://sahi.co.in/w/?q=ant